# Jira On Demand Integration with Bamboo

Tags: jira, bamboo

I am having troubles with configuring our on demand JIRA instance with a hosted Bamboo Server. There are no Firewalls at the moment.
This is what I see in when I open a JIRA issue:

> JIRA is having difficulty contacting Bamboo (XXXX.Atlassian.net). If
>   this condition persists, please contact your JIRA administrators.

WIthin Bamboo I have setup an Application LInk with the JIRA server. This works fine as I can see JIRA Issues linked to a Build. I did the same in JIRA as well. I added Bamboo as an application link and set the link as primary. For some reason JIRA tries to contact a on Demand Version of Bamboo. Any idea why?

This question with screenshots was also posted [here](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/250519/jira-on-demand-integration-with-bamboo) in Atlassian forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a firewall issue. Started to work after we fixed that.